# jQuery or PHP capitalise string and concatenate in one function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

I originally had this very separated out and it was a long function, to take three different words, capitalise the first letter and then store them in a new variable, concatenated.

Instead I am trying to find a solution where this code can be minimised and doesn't have to have a different function for the concatenation, another for the capitalisation etc.

How would you do this? The three strings are `wordChoiceOnce, wordChoiceTwo and wordChoiceThree`

So I need this really (pseudo-code):

```
function saveUsername(wordChoiceOnce, wordChoiceTwo, wordChoiceThree){
     // capitalise first letter of all words
     // concatenate all words together in order
     //store words in var username;
}
```

EDIT: Immediately after I have stored this var, I planned to pass it to a PHP variable. So maybe it would be easier to offer a PHP solution instead? And pass each word to PHP, then capitalise and concat.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a built-in function to capitalize words, but [CSS does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform).

Comment: @Blazemonger the variable won't be output in HTML, needs to be stored in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has ucwords, which has been [ported](http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords/) to javascript.  So, that well-known function gets us something like this:

```
function saveUsername(wordChoiceOnce, wordChoiceTwo, wordChoiceThree){
    function ucwords(str) {
      //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/ucwords/
      // original by: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
      // improved by: Waldo Malqui Silva
      // improved by: Robin
      // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
      // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
      //    input by: James (http://www.james-bell.co.uk/)
      //   example 1: ucwords('kevin van  zonneveld');
      //   returns 1: 'Kevin Van  Zonneveld'
      //   example 2: ucwords('HELLO WORLD');
      //   returns 2: 'HELLO WORLD'

      return (str + '')
        .replace(/^([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])|\s+([a-z\u00E0-\u00FC])/g, function($1) {
          return $1.toUpperCase();
        });
    }

    return ucwords(wordChoice1) + ' ' + ucwords(wordChoiceTwo) + ' ' + ucwords(wordChoiceThree);
}
```

Comment: I'm actually planning on converting the string to a PHP variable for use in PHP right after this. Would it therefore be easier to send each individual word to a PHP var and then use built-in PHP to capitalise before concatenation? I'm more comfortable with JS but it makes sense to do it there? Can you help with that?

Comment: If you can do it on the server side, then it's much better. Remember that one of the rules of programming is to never trust user input. Any user could easily disable JavaScript or even alter the script to make the text go in their way.

Comment: @SparoHawk it doesn't matter so much if they do adjust it, it's more for looks than having to 100% be like that. So it shouldn't hurt too much if they do create a username by adjusting the JS.

Comment: @Francesca - Doesn't really matter.  I prefer to have that kind of logic on the server, but others would go the other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function saveUsername(wordChoiceOnce, wordChoiceTwo, wordChoiceThree){

var res = capitaliseFirstLetter(wordChoiceOnce) + capitaliseFirstLetter(wordChoiceTwo) + capitaliseFirstLetter(wordChoiceThree);

}
```

using this function :

```
function capitaliseFirstLetter(str)
{
    return str.toString().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.toString().slice(1);
}
```

Comment: I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined

Comment: Now I get: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined  :P

Comment: Where is "str" coming from, shouldn't this be as in my code my variables wordChoiceOne etc ... otherwise what is it using to capitalise.

Comment: I will make a fiddle for you ;)

Comment: function capitaliseFirstLetter(str) is a function, and str is a paramater owned only by this function, if we want to call this function later, we will use it by passing the first, second and third string.

Comment: Hmm, I think I see. My issue is that this is not bringing in the variables of wordChoiceOne etc. The word is already stored in there. It should pass the contents of those vars, capitalise and then concat. You shouldn't have to put them in hardcoded? I already have the values stored.

Comment: Also it still doesn't work, see this. When you set the words then click big green button it should show alert(res) as in your code, but it doesn't work. http://marmiteontoast.co.uk/fyp/login-register/register-username-builder.php

Comment: it works in fiddle it should work on your web site. Could you make an edit with your code please

Comment: Error suggests that it is not able to pass the capitalse function because you are not reading in the string. str is not assigned and has no value.

Comment: Don't call me darling, please. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: let's keep cool. The function works fine, as you can see in the fiddle, just check your code.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples above missed to lower case the rest of the string.

Here is an example:

```
function saveUsername(wordChoiceOnce, wordChoiceTwo, wordChoiceThree)
{
    var username = capitalize(wordChoiceOnce) + capitalize(wordChoiceTwo) + capitalize(wordChoiceThree);

    alert(username);
}

function capitalize(word)
{
    return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}

saveUsername('john', 'SMITH', 'DoeSon');
```

Comment: Just to note, the original request did not ask for this; however, it is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not provide an extensible solution that encompasses any length of string?

```
function saveUsername(wordArray){
    var str = '';

    for(var i = 0, len = wordArray.length; i < len; i++){
        str += wordArray[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + wordArray[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();

        if(i < (len-1)){
            str += ' ';
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
saveUsername([wordChoiceOne,wordChoiceTwo,wordChoiceThree]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:  My solution is in JavaScript, so not ideal.

I would suggest using a separate function for capitalizing the first letter; however, if you want this done in a single function, this will work:

```
function saveUsername () {
    var arr = [],
        i   = arguments.length,
        word, username;
    while (i--) {
        word = arguments[i];
        arr.unshift( word.charAt(0).toUpperCase(), word.substr(1) );
    }
    username = arr.join('');
}

saveUsername( 'one', 'two', 'three' );
```

This method will work for any number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a capitalize method on the string prototype.

Then you can just so a little bit of manipulation to get the strings from your arguments, capitalize them, and then join them.

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
};

function saveUserName(a,b,c) { 
    var argArray = [];

    for (item in arguments) {
        argArray.push(arguments[item].toLowerCase().capitalize());
    }

    var joined = argArray.join('');
    alert(joined);
} 

saveUserName('frank', 'jim', 'jen');
```